# Good SQL engine for huge rows in a single column table

Tags: php, mysql, nosql

I have a table where I store *almost any English word*. This table is for a Scrabble type word game currently I am working on. Here is the syntax,

```
create table words(
    `word` varchar(50),
    primary key `word`
)
```

This table will be very big. And I have to check every time if the given word exists when gamer makes a move.

I am using mysql. Currently I have stored *ENABLE* words there.  My question is when I start adding more words and gamers start to play wont it be performing low? If so, is there any way I can optimize it? Does NO-SQL has anything to do with this scenario?

Comment: Just try it. Chances are you will run out of words to input long before MySQL starts breaking a sweat.

Comment: According to [this source](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language), there are about 250.000 English words. Any DBMS worth its salt has no problem whatsoever with that amount.

Comment: I have a table with 120 million rows and 25 columns - just index correctly and there will not noticed any performance hit

Comment: Do you have any actual evidence to suggest that it will perform badly, or are you just worrying before the event? You'e only talking about 500k words

Comment: is an "id" int() advisable in this case?

Comment: If you use an int as an ID column as Matt suggests, make it your primary key and be sure to index your word column.  I'm pretty sure that MySql will index the primary key automatically so you are all set there if you keep word as your primary key.

Comment: If a scrabble board is 15 blocks in length then the maximum amount of characters needed per varchar would be 15? `varchar(15)`

Comment: @Silver89 It'll depend on board size. Target board size is 21.

Comment: @ManseUK do you think the table definition in the question is properly indexed? I dont bother give an  `id int` as all search will be around word

Comment: @Shiplu you have created no indexes ! Read this -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: @Manse The `PRIMARY KEY` *is* an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no performance problems but if you are worried about performance you can keep this in mind:

Using LIKE instead of = will cause slower queries if you have a lot of rows.  (but you must have an extremely large amount of rows for a noticeable difference)

Also, you might do some testing to see which performs better on large tables, select count or select * or select word.

Comment: For scrabble, LIKE shouldn't be used... you want to see if the actual word is in the dictionary

Comment: @MarkBaker that is until you want to implement the scrabble dictionary perhaps?

Comment: then LIKE isn't particularly useful, because you're testing against different letter orderings and you'd need a whole series of LIKEs (or something completely different).... but using dictionaries in scrabble is cheating :)

Comment: @MarkBaker good point :)  although using dictionaries is only cheating in competition I believe...otherwise I cheat all the time ;)

Comment: The game engine will check for words existence for validity. Its not cheating.